# Determining the meaning of a challenge coin

Tags: visual, cipher

[image: Front][image: Back]

I saw this rather cool looking challenge coin the other day, and I was wondering what the associated binary on the back of it means, as it isn't standard ASCII.

In plaintext:

> 010110100101000100101010100101001111111011

Comment: i want this coin!

Comment: I'm inclined to believe the digits are random, but I found this cool coincidence (probably) - near the bottom, there's a gap that seems slightly larger than the rest, and if we treat the digits starting from here (01011010...) it turns out that the parity of the letters in NATIONAL exactly match up with this. (could not replicate with SECURITY, or AGENCY) Or maybe I'm just reading too much into this.

Comment: If anyone wants to know more about challenge coins in general, the great "99% invisible" podcast did an episode about them: [Coin Check](https://99percentinvisible.org/episode/coin-check/).

Comment: Also, Oray, if you want the coin it's on Ebay for 1500 dollars. https://www.ebay.com/itm/National-Security-Agency-NSA-Nuclear-Command-Control-Military-Challenge-Coin-/192440155098

Comment: I didn't post that in the original section as I didn't want this to be seen as an attempt to sell the coin.

Comment: Especially because it isn't mine!

Comment: The number of stars and electrons and leaves could be relevant on the left image. On the right image, the 7 lines emanating from Maryland(?), and the points where the bomber, sub, and missile touch the edge of the circle could all be relevant if there is a message. There are 42 bits, but that doesn't seem to work as 6 7-bit ASCII characters.

Comment: It could be 8-bit ASCII with a 2 bit mask.

Comment: @phenomist Actually, the parity of AGENCY (111011) lines up with the end of the message.  So if the digits are the parity of the letters, the message could start with NATIONAL and end in AGENCY.  I couldn't think of anything that would fit in between though (SECURITY is not anywhere).

Comment: I don't know if parity is a useful metric because for just national and agency alone, there are 100+ words with the same parity (https://pastebin.com/raw/NEurZ5cC). If you take into account: all the bits, the fact that you could start anywhere, that 1-length strings (like digits and punctuation) could be separating words, then you can almost make it say anything. You might find an answer that seems plausible but it would be very hard to prove that that exact variation is what the creator intended.

Comment: Considering any starting point or reflection, it doesn't make words from 7- or 8-bit ASCII, nor is it a 4-, 5-, 6-, 7- or 8-bit offset added to 64 or 65 to get ASCII. Doesn't seem to be a rot*n* encoding of these either—though that, I didn't check thoroughly. If this isn't random, it doesn't seem to be anything trivial.